# DFS scan on a completed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

I have some interesting question that I would like to get your help:
Let's say I have a graph (Data structure) with n(n-1)/2 edges, which means, completed graph.
How many possible different DFS trees can I get from one DFS scan from some random element in the graph?

Comment: I believe you meant n*(n-1)/2 edges. If I understand correctly: there are n ways you can choose starting node. Then, since you can go from any vertex to any other vertex, there are n - 1 ways of choosing the next node. And so on. The total number of ways would be n!

Comment: why not (n-1)! ?

Comment: If you start from a particular node, yes, it would be (n - 1)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is interesting. I believe you are talking about complete graph with **n** vertices and **n(n-1)/2** edges in between them.
If we begin depth first search (DFS) from any vertex, it will end up visiting exactly **n** vertices. In DFS, we keep track of visited vertices so that we will not visit them once they are visited and hence outgoing option reduces as long as DFS progresses. We can summarize this as:

- There are total n options to choose first vertex.
- There are total n-1 options to choose second vertex as 1 vertex is already visited.
- There are total n-2 options to choose third vertex as 2 vertices are already visited.
- There are total n-3 options to choose third vertex as 3 vertices are already visited.
- And so on . . .
- There is only 1 option to choose nth vertex.

Hence, different possible DFS trees that we can get from DFS in such graph is :

```
Total ways = n*(n-1)*(n-2)*(n-3)*....*1
           = n! ( n factorial )
```

Comment: I am not sure about the first total you mentioned, if I select random vertice, I stay with (n-1) option to choose the next one, and therefore it will be (n-1)! ? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As you mentioned in your question "How many possible different DFS trees can I get from one DFS scan from some random element in the graph?". Since, starting vertex in DFS in a random value , which has possibility of being one of **n** possible vertex.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it's not a tree but a list of nodes of the given complete graph. Thus, the question is: How many permutations of n nodes of the graph? Apparently, the answer is n!.